# CCSpriteBatchNode or NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently trying to create an endlessly scrolling background with a character who jumps up and down and collects items that come along the way.
My problem lies with the items that need to be created and then moved.

I've looked at CCSpriteBatchNode and NSMutableArray but I'm not sure which to use.

I reviewed Steffen Itterheim's example from his book regarding creating bullets while initializing and then using them when needed.
I thought that this would be inefficient and taxing on the iPhone. Also, aren't all the bullets continuously updated even if they are not visible, using up even more of the iPhone's limited memory and CPU?

On the other hand, if I had a NSMutableArray and added the items as I needed them and updated a selective few that currently exist, would this be more efficient.

Thus, my main problem is choosing between NSMutableArray or CCSpriteBatchNode and finding out which is the most efficient in creating numerous, continuously  updating objects.

Thank you!

Comment: I have not read the book, but it would be unlikely that the author would coin an 'inefficient' example. My best advice is 'make it work' and then determine whether you have a performance issue. If you do, come back here with specifics on your implementation with a focused question. Is is hard to give you  any practical advice without some details : how many sprites, what actions are they performing while scrolling, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cocos, CCSpriteBatchNode is much better if you plan to have many of your objects on the screen at the same time. CCSpriteBatchNode only "draws" the object once, then propogates it repeatedly in your view. This saves a lot of precious CPU resources. This is why CCSpriteBatchNode is used with bullets because usually there are many on the screen.

Also, if your objects appear frequently, even if there are just one or two on the screen at once, CCSpriteBatchNode will use the cached drawing rather than redrawing, still saving CPU resources.

I recommend sticking with the Cocos objects when you can, as they are designed to improve performance for reasons like this, over the native Apple objects like NSMutableArray.

However, if you insist on using NSMutableArray, still consider CCArray instead if you are using Cocos. But CCSpriteBatchNode is probably going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes entirely outside the screen are quickly dismissed, and if you set a node's visible property to NO it will be dismissed right away, which means there's basically no performance penalty for invisible nodes.

Caching many objects is actually faster than creating and releasing them at runtime, even if that means you'll always have 400 or so of them in memory. That requires maybe 200 KB of memory at most and avoids frequent alloc/dealloc cycles which you will want to avoid as much as possible, particularly on 1st/2nd gen devices.